# Why sometimes Chrome Dev Tool shows scss file instead of compiled css file?

Tags: css, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, scss-mixins

[image]
As the above image shows, while inspecting some elements, the Chrome Dev Tool shows it is related with a .scss file, when I click the file, it is empty. I test it with Safari on macOS, it also shows this scss file but when clicked, it correctly shows the content of this scss file. It seems the dev tool is somehow bugged here.

Anyway, my question is, on what condition would Chrome Dev Tools(and the like) shows scss file instead of compiled css file?

Comment: those scss files has a source map files generated while compiling to css, you can find them right beside the actual `scss` or the `css` files

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You do not have to show the scss file please uncheck **Enable CSS source maps** checkbox

1. **Step-1:-** Please open chrome Developer tools
2. **Step-2:-** Press **F1** key
3. **Step-3:-** uncheck **Enable CSS source maps** checkbox

[image]

Answer (score 3):

That is because a `typography.css.map` file is present in the same directory as the `typography.css` file. Chrome recognizes this map file and displays `typography.scss` instead of `typography.css`. This also works for mozilla too.

Comment: I happens without that. Please see the accepted answer.